# set height view to match parent with animation in android

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-linearlayout

How to change the height of the view to match_parent when there is a click?

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    final int startHeight;
    final int targetHeight;
    private final boolean isOpen;
    View view;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int height, boolean isOpen) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHeight = height;
        this.isOpen = isOpen;
        startHeight = view.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
     protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHeight;
        if (isOpen) {
            newHeight = (int) (startHeight + (targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            newHeight =  (int) (startHeight + targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        }
        view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(view, MATCH_PARENT, false);
resizeAnimation.setDuration(500);
view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your animation doesn't work because you are passing `View.MATCH_PARENT`(which value is **-1**) as target height. Quoting the documentation:

> int MATCH_PARENT [...]
>   Constant Value: **-1** (0xffffffff)

You have to pass the real target height. You can accomplish that measuring the future target height in the parent layout after it has been rendered (I recommend you `ViewTreeObserver.onGlobalLayout()` for that).